# Add attribute value to HTML tag where value is equal to HTML tag's content

Tags: php, jquery, html

I've found many similar questions but none quite did the trick for me. 
Here's my situation: 
I've got a span, the content of this span is a number dynamically inserted by Jquery. 
This same span has an attribute, I want the value of this attribute to be equal to the number.

I have tried to put the number in a variable and then add it trough .attr with Jquery but no luck there. Here's the code:

```
<script>

var value= $('#min').html();
$('#min').attr('data-category', value);

</script> 


<span class="filter" data-category="" id="min"></span>
```

Any pointers will be greatly appreciated! Thanks :)

Comment: Are you sure, that is all you have - no `document.ready` ,no jquery ?

Comment: Your code works as-is if ordered properly. http://jsfiddle.net/8zRLR/1/

Comment: *Edit: Nevermind, I'm wrong, see below.*

Comment: If the number was added by jQuery, you need to ensure that your code runs AFTER that code.

Comment: @SpikeX - No you can't. The `.data()` function will _retrieve_ html attribute values, but it won't _set_ them. Any values set with `.data()` are stored in jQuery's own structure, not as element attributes.

Comment: @nnnnnn Oh, really? I didn't know that, that's kind of silly ... you would think it would go both ways.

Comment: @SpikeX - Well any values set with `.data()` can be retrieved again with further `.data()` calls, and `.data()` lets you store values that are not valid as attributes (e.g., it can store objects), so... If you want to set the actual attribute value just use `.attr()`.

Comment: I was thinking, the data within the span comes from a Jquery UI slider. Is it possible to add this value to an attribute?

Please see: http://jqueryui.com/slider/#range-vertical

Comment: I now tried:
var value = $( "#slider" ).slider( "values", 0 );
$('#min').attr('data-category', value);

Still doesn't do the trick but I feel it has to be close, any thoughts?

Comment: Ok, so here is how I solved it. This might be a bit more specific then my original question but maybe it can help someone else:

First I use the change event of the Jquery UI slider to detect any changes made on the slider handles: 

$( "YOURSLIDER-DIV-SPAN-WHATEVER" ).slider({
  change: function( event, ui ) {}
});

Answer (score 0):

You are rendering your script before you render the HTML tag.

You have to either wrap your javascript around the jQuery $(document).ready() to trigger the code once the DOM is ready, or put it after you render the HTML.

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    var value= $('#min').html();
    $('#min').attr('data-category', value);
});

</script> 


<span class="filter" data-category="" id="min"></span>
```

Comment: Adding a ready handler may not be enough given that "the content of this span is a number dynamically inserted by Jquery" (which may happen after your ready handler runs).

Comment: A shorter way of doing this is to pass $() a function, like this: `$(function() { /* init code here */ });`. Same thing with less clutter.

Comment: Thanks for all the response, It's overwhelming. 
@nnnnnn, you are right this only sets the initial value it has to update when the number is changed.

Comment: How can I have it check continually for changes within the span?

Answer (score 0):

[working example](http://jsbin.com/ihilak/22/edit)

**added jquery watch plugin**, to catch content changes, maybe exists better solution but this works when you dynamically change your content with jquery

don't forget clear your old content

```
$('#min').html('');
```

before inserting new

```
$('#min').html('new content');
```

to ensure that **watch()** function will fire

Comment: Hi Lukas, Thanks for your reply. I checked it out but can't seem to find any changes in the span after clicking. Only here: $('#min').html('').html('c');

What am I missing?

Comment: you wanted to dynamically change span attribute when content of your span will be changed by another script ... this code emuates dynamic change of your span (by clicking on 1st sentence)... content of your span will be changed from **b** to **c** and also **attribute of span b is dyn changed**

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a ton for all your help! I've finally figured this out.
Ok, so here is how I solved it. This might be a bit more specific then my original question but maybe it can help someone else:

First I use the change event of the Jquery UI slider to detect any changes made on the slider handles:

```
$( "YOURSLIDER-DIV-SPAN-WHATEVER-ID-CLASS" ).slider({
change: function( event, ui ) {}
});
```

Then with the value method I put the value of the slider handle in a variable. (since I use a range slider I've got 2 of these, on for the top handle and one for the bottom)

```
var value = $( "YOURSLIDER-DIV-SPAN-WHATEVER-ID-CLASS" ).slider( "values", 0 );
var value = $( "YOURSLIDER-DIV-SPAN-WHATEVER-ID-CLASS" ).slider( "values", 1 );
```

Then I use .attr to add the variable to both the bottom and the top slider handles:

```
$('#min').attr('data-category', bottom_value);
$('#max').attr('data-category', top_value);
```